# jQuery Datatables Legacy Loading animation

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table using the jQuery Datatable plugin (legacy). I recieve my data from a server. Since sometimes the server response takes some seconds, I want to show a loading animation. How can I achive this?

Comment: Show a loader image before you call your server and on success or error you can hide the loader.

Comment: Thats how I would do it as well, but there is no success or error method for this jquery datatable plugin

Answer (score 5):

Lets say you create an animated gif by using the http://www.ajaxload.info/ service and download it as `ajax-loader.gif`. Then you can override `oLanguage.sLoadingRecords` to show the gif like this :

```
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
  oLanguage: {
      sLoadingRecords: '<img src="path/to/ajax-loader.gif">'
    }
});
```

[**docs**](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/i18n) for `oLanguage.sLoadingRecords` :

> When using Ajax sourced data and during the first draw when DataTables
>   is gathering the data, this message is shown in an empty row in the
>   table to indicate to the end user the the data is being loaded. Note
>   that this parameter is not used when loading data by server-side
>   processing, just Ajax sourced data with client-side processing.

Answer (score 2):

Datatables has this built in! Just use :

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
   "bProcessing": true
});
```

Read about it here! http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#bProcessing